# Добавить блоку класс если существует sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка

Доброго времени суток.

Существует такая разметка:

```
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar-right"></div>
</div>
```

sidebar'ы выводятся не на всех страницах.

Как с помощью JS, классу `.box` добавить класс:

1. `sider` если существует  `sidebar-left` или `sidebar-right`.
2. `allsider` если существуют оба `sidebar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var sidebarLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-left');
var sidebarRight = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-right');
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

if(sidebarLeft.length && sidebarRight.length)
 for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     boxes[i].setAttribute('class', boxes[i].getAttribute('class') + ' allsider');
else if(sidebarLeft.length || sidebarRight.length)
 for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)
     boxes[i].setAttribute('class', boxes[i].getAttribute('class') + ' sider');
```

```css
.sider {
  color: green;
}

.allsider {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="sidebar-left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="sidebar-right"></div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Не ожидал столь быстрого ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете jquery и скорость выборки элементов для вас не существенна, то можно сделать так:

```
var sidebar = $('div[class^="sidebar-"]');

var boxs = $('.box');

if (sidebar.length == 2) {
    boxs.addClass('allsider');
} else if (sidebar.length == 1) {
    boxs.addClass('sider');
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/f5h9cd3g/